# Spring Boot Embedded MongoDB - Run script from java to create function and upload massive data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot-test, embedded-mongodb

I'm using in **Spring Boot**, ***Embedded MongoDB** to do build testing.
I need some Collections created, some Documents loaded and a function created in the "system.js" Collection to manage a sequence.
I couldn't figure out how to do this with properties file (like what happens with H2 db)
I tried to do everything via java in the test configuration phase:

- the creation of the Collections and the loading of the Documents via Java I did it using ***mongoTemplate.insert(...)*** (a Document at the time unfortunately, but I'm satisfied)

**-for creating the function through Java I HAVE NOT FOUND A SOLUTION**

So, i managed to execute these commands with java:

```
db.createCollection ("dbSequence");
```

```
db.dbSequence.insert ({"seq": "subNumber", "value": 1, "_ class": "com.ilsole24ore.ordiniTermed.model.DbSequence"});
```

this is the function that I create through the mongodb commands but I can't with java:

```
db.system.js.save ({_ id: 'getNextSequence',
    value: function getNextSequence (seqName) {
       var sequenceDocument = db.dbSequence.findAndModify ({
          query: {seq: seqName},
          update: {$ inc: {value: 1}},
          new: true
       });
       return sequenceDocument.value;
    }
});
```

- the next problem is how to call the function

has anyone already had this need? thanks everyone for the help.